# Identifying a (power?) socket

Tags: electrical, socket

We found this socket in a house in Belgium of the 50's. There are no wires connected, and there seems to be no numbers or identification on it.

Does anybody know what it is?

[image: Socket]

Comment: A country could be helpful ;-)

Comment: The CEBEC logo at the top points to Belgium https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEBEC.  CVF at the bottom didn't help me.

Comment: It's indeed Belgium

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google really did not want to help, because any such queries were glutted by travel adapters with all the different socket codes (A through J). Americans may note those cover only US NEMA 1 and 5, and don't cover NEMA 7, 15, L5, 23 and many others intended for heavy-duty use.

That is the situation here.  This socket is for heavy-duty loads.

It is not terribly unlike [those pictured here](https://www.plugsocketmuseum.nl/Belgian_3hd.html) in pictures 17-20.  This one has a different keying, so is for a different phase relationship or perhaps different current/fusing.

Comment: The pin slope is wrong  by 90 degrees for pictures 17-20, but you have found the manufacturer.

Comment: @Jasen oh, snap!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Type I socket, but it's listed for APAC and not Europe:

[Type I Socket](https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeI.htm#targetText=Plug%20Type%20I&targetText=The%20Type%20I%20plug%20has,flat%20pins%2C%20exists%20as%20well.&targetText=Australia's%20standard%20plug%2Fsocket%20system,the%20ground%20pin%20is%20wider.)

Comment: We assumed that first too, but the dimensions don't seem to coincide. The angle between the slanted holes is 90 degrees, and it's less for type I. Also, here are 4 holes